# Use GET instead of POST for AJAX call

Tags: 7, ajax

I was wondering if anyone had any tips for use a GET call with ajax forms instead of POST?

One of our ajax calls is returning some JSON that we want to be cached in the browser.  If we can switch the call to GET then that caching will happen for us.

Comment: can you tell us what's your purpose?

Comment: what if you add `$.ajaxSetup({ cache:true });`? Be aware that this will affect all subsequent AJAX requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to use GET instead of POST, but Drupal sends a lot of information about dom-elements and loaded css/js, so that it is often too long for a GET request..

```
var ax = new Drupal.ajax("element-name", this, element_settings);
ax.options.type = "GET";
```

If you do not use these, you can strip them:

```
//Override parameters for Get Requests
var backup = Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSerialize;
Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSerialize = function(element, options) {
  if(options.type != "GET") backup.call(this, element, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Views Ajax Get](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ajax_get) module to convert post request to get

> This module will make your ajax-enabled Views, use GET instead of POST.